# Nattable IColumnAccessor ClassNotFound

Tags: nattable

I tried to use simple Nattable as in Vogella tutorial mentioned but I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/data/IColumnAccessor
    at com.mioplus.mioredapp.view.ContentFactory.createContent(ContentFactory.java:14)
    at com.mioplus.mioredapp.dialogs.TreeDialog$1.handleEvent(TreeDialog.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.mioplus.mioredapp.dialogs.LoginDialog$1.widgetSelected(LoginDialog.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
```

I am developing a plugin application and using Luna 4.4.2, anyone that can help me, I added all jars to build path, and even class is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a startup issue. At the time you are opening your LoginDialog the nattable.core bundle is not yet loaded. So either there is a dependency missing or your product configuration does not specify the dependency to nattable.core.

Comment: tnx for such a quick reply, In fact I have problem with adding nattable update site to target, and i get missing bundle org.eclipse.equinex.common 0.0.0 error, but i have it in my plugin dependencies, really confused, i tried all 1.x version even on Neon but result is same

Comment: Have you specified the target definition like shown in the tutorial? That should contain all dependencies

Comment: yes, i followed step by step, as a target we are using redapp target platform, now for 1.3 version i got Unable to locate org.eclipse.nubela.widgets.nattable.core.feature.feature.group :-((

Comment: And when are you trying to show a NatTable? In a LoginDialog in a lifecycle handler? Or did you really follow the example and create a part?

Comment: I added it to one of my composites, and dynamically add it to a dialog, i have no problem with tableviewer in this situation, it's really interesting that i added it to eclipse ide but i can't add it to target

Comment: The TableViewer is JFace and therefore part of the platform. NatTable is an additional bundle. The question is which dependencies are missing in your platform to make it work. The NatTable features in version 1.4 should bring in all required bundles. If you use an earlier version some dependencies like Apache Commons Logging are typically missing. So which version do you use and do you use feature or plugin based product configurations.

Comment: I am developing a plug-in project in luna 4.4, i checked for all dependencies: i have Commons logging version 1.1 as a dependency, also swt jface and equinox 3.6. we are using Sabre Red app as target platform. I tried nattable by 1.4, 1.3, 1.2 , ... but same result, even i used sourceforge version but again error is same

Comment: and does that ominous Sabre Red app target platform contain the NatTable features?

Comment: :-))) No it doesn't, I added everything that is mentioned in tutorial

Comment: well it seems to be an issue with the target definition and I can't tell anything without detailed information. You need to check the target platform state and check what is missing. This should typically be stated in the target platform state view.